# Upgrade with backports installed

Tags: upgrade, backport

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with backports for TexLive.

Ubuntu 12.10 is to contain the same version of TexLive that backport provides currently to 12.04.

I, of course, want to move from backport to the normal version of TexLive available in Ubuntu 12.10 repositories.

How do I handle the situation? Do I upgrade the normal way and everything will be taken care of i.e. my TexLive installation will now be from repositories instead of backports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct, you don't really need to do anything, you can just upgrade the normal way.